# docker-compose: site running but css not applying

Tags: css, django, docker-compose

I am trying to run my Django app (V 1.8.6) in a docker container using docker-compose.

This is my setting.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/srv/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

This is my docker compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  #
  # Nettle API server
  #
  nettle:
    image: mcvitty_img
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=sites.production.settings
    ports:
      - "80:8000"

volumes:
  bluebell: {}
  postgres-data: {}
  rabbitmq-data: {}
```

I am successfully running the collect static in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN python manage.py migrate --settings=sites.production.settings --fake-initial
RUN python manage.py sitetree_resync_apps --settings=sites.production.settings
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --settings=sites.production.settings --noinput
```

But sadly this is the result:

[image]

This are the logs I get:

```
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/widget.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/js/all.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/autocomplete.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/remote.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/text_widget.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/autocomplete.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/addanother.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/widget.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/js/datatableview.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/images/frontimage1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/addanother.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/images/frontimage2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/text_widget.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/images/frontimage3.png HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/remote.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/images/frontimage4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/images/frontimage6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/images/frontimage8.png HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/images/frontimage7.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/images/frontimage5.png HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
nettle_1  | [29/Sep/2020 15:08:19] "GET /static/js/datatableview.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4463
```

If I hop into the container I can see the static folder has been created:

[image]

Comment: Go into "inspect" on your wewbpage, and have a look at the path it's trying to use for the css ...

Comment: Under "console" there you may see the issue as well, with a file failing to load, or eg. "strict MIME checking is enabled", so it's refused to load it with a "text/html" type

Comment: Probably your Dockerfile, when you copy your code across.

Comment: I suggest setting `STATIC_ROOT = "/static/"` and just leaving it at that. Create the `/static` directory off root as part of your Dockerfile, and when you run `collectstatic` that shoudl put everything there. Simpler than trying to drop it under your base like you have.

Comment: Or `/srv/static/`, like you've done with the `MEDIA_ROOT` ...

Comment: Should I have both STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL set to "/static/"?

Comment: `STATIC_URL` is just a prefix that the django server uses. If you're running with ´DEBUG = False` and have run `collectstatic`, it's `STATIC_ROOT` where your system will look.